# Is there a way to inverse a table to change the column headers?

Tags: excel, vba, validation, conditional-formatting

I have a list of names in the first column of my table, and the second column is where I've listed all functions that person is trained in. Is there a way to create a new table that links to this constantly changing table (as more people become trained) that keeps adding people under each function as they become trained in it?

The first table is important, but I also want to display this same information in the second method without having to edit the file twice.

In more detail, here is a sample 2 rows on my first table:

```
Tom Jones  | Phone, social media, coffee
Lila Jones | Phone, coffee, voicemail
```

I want a separate linked column or table that shows me:
PHONE: Tom Jones, Lila Jones, etc etc

Comment: Yes is possible.  Because of your data structure is not formatted into columns, you may need to do a combo of vlookup with find ().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim c As Range, dict, arr, v, l, shtOut As Worksheet

    Set shtOut = Sheets("Sheet2")

    shtOut.UsedRange.ClearContents

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set c = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") '<< first name in list

    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0 '<< run until hit an empty name cell
        l = Trim(c.Offset(0, 1).Value)
        If Len(l) > 0 Then
            arr = Split(l, ",")
            For Each v In arr
                v = UCase(Trim(v))
                If dict.exists(v) Then
                    dict(v) = dict(v) & ", " & c.Value
                Else
                    dict.Add v, c.Value
                End If
            Next v
        End If
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    With shtOut.Range("A2")   '<< output list starts here
        .Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
        .Offset(0, 1).Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = _
                                      Application.Transpose(dict.items)
    End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like so:

```
Table 1 
[ID] AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
[Name] TEXT

Table 2
[ID] Integer PRIMARY KEY
[Functions] TEXT
```

Then in Database tools > Relationships create the reference from Table 1 to Table 2, check all 3 referential integrity boxes. This is a more normalized approach.